# Good alternatives to PushBots

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Good Afternoon all.
For some reason, i haven't figured how to correctly use Pushbots. 
I tried but it did not recognize my emulator.

Are there other good alternatives to pushbots that i can use to send GCM notifications to my android device?